# Adjust for best performance

Tags: c++, windows, internals

I am wondering if it is possible to toggle the "Adjust for best performance" radio box in Windows' Advanced Settings trough C/C++. I have looked around for answers and just stopped at SystemParametersInfo:

```
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETUIEFFECTS, 0, false, 0);
```

But this did not work (neither did it work with requireUAC in the manifest).

Is this do-able?

Comment: 'did not work' means what?

Comment: it does not change anything, but it returns TRUE